# Show that Ergodic Theorem is a special case of Kingman's Subadditive Ergodic Theorem.

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

A version of Birkhoff's Ergodic Theorem is the following:

> **Theorem 1:** Take $\xi\in L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$. If $\theta$ preserves $\mathbb{P}$, then $$\dfrac{\xi(\omega)+\xi(\theta\omega)+\cdots+\xi(\theta^{n-1}\omega)}{n}\longrightarrow_{a.s,\ L^{1}}\mathbb{E}(\xi|\mathcal{J}),$$ where $\mathcal{J}$ is the invariance $\sigma-$algebra. In particular, if the system $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P},\theta)$ is ergodic (so that $\mathcal{J}$ is trivial), then we have $$\dfrac{\xi(\omega)+\xi(\theta\omega)+\cdots+\xi(\theta^{n-1}\omega)}{n}\longrightarrow_{a.s,\ L^{1}}\mathbb{E}\xi.$$

A version of Kingman's Subadditive Ergodic Theorem is the following:

> **Theroem 2:** Let $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $L^{1}$ random variables and let $\theta$ be an MPT on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ such that the following sub-additive property holds:$$X_{n+m}(\omega)\leq X_{n}+X_{m}(\theta^{n}\omega),\ \ n,m\in\mathbb{N}.$$ Then we have $$\dfrac{X_{n}}{n}\longrightarrow_{a.s,\ L^{1}}\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{\mathbb{E}(X_{n}|\mathcal{J})}{n},\ \text{as}\ n\rightarrow\infty.$$ In particular, if $\theta$ is ergodic, then $$\dfrac{X_{n}}{n}\longrightarrow_{a.s,\ L^{1}}\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{\mathbb{E}X_{n}}{n},\ \text{as}\ n\rightarrow\infty.$$

Now, I want to show Theorem 2 implies Theorem 1. I had some attempts but got stuck in the end:

Let $Y$ be a $L^{1}-$random variable and $\theta$ is an  MPT. Define $$X_{n}:=Y(\omega)+\cdots+Y(\theta^{n-1}\omega).$$  Then, $$X_{n}(\omega)+X_{m}(\theta^{n}\omega)=Y(\omega)+\cdots+Y(\theta^{n-1}\omega)+Y(\theta^{n}\omega)+\cdots+Y(\theta^{n+m-1}\omega)=X_{n+m}(\omega).$$

Therefore, by the Sub-additive Ergodic Theorem, we have $$\dfrac{Y(\omega)+\cdots+Y(\theta^{n-1}\omega)}{n}=\dfrac{X_{n}}{n}\longrightarrow_{a.s,\ L^{1}}\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{(\mathbb{E}X_{n}|\mathcal{J})}{n}.$$

However, how do I show $$\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\dfrac{(\mathbb{E}X_{n}|\mathcal{J})}{n}=\mathbb{E}(Y|\mathcal{J})?$$

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $$\mathbb{E}[Y \circ \theta^k | \mathcal{J}] = \mathbb{E}[Y | \mathcal{J}]$$
since then $\mathbb{E}[X_n | \mathcal{J}] = n \mathbb{E}[Y | \mathcal{J}]$ for any $n$.

For this, pick an $A \in \mathcal{J}$. We need to show that $$\mathbb{E}[1_A Y \circ \theta^k ] = \mathbb{E}[1_A \mathbb{E}[Y| \mathcal{J}]]$$

The right hand side is given by $\mathbb{E}[1_A Y]$. For the left hand side, note that since $A \in \mathcal{J}$, $\theta^{-k}(A) = A$. Then we have that $1_A \circ \theta^k = 1_{\theta^{-k}(A)} = 1_A$ and so the left hand side is nothing but
$$\mathbb{E}[(1_A Y) \circ \theta^k] = \int_{\theta^k(\Omega)} 1_A Y d \theta_*^k \mathbb{P} = \int_{\Omega} 1_A Y d \theta_*^k \mathbb{P} = \mathbb{E}[1_A Y]$$
since $\theta^k$ is measure preserving and $\mathbb{P}(\theta^k(\Omega)) = 1$ as a result. Indeed, $$\mathbb{P}(\theta^k(\Omega)) = \mathbb{P}(\theta^{-k}(\theta^k(\Omega))) \geq \mathbb{P}(\Omega) = 1$$ since $\Omega \subseteq \theta^{-k}(\theta^k(\Omega))$.

Comment: Nice answer! Thank you!!

Comment: one question, by the change of variable formula, we have $$\int_{\Omega}\mathbb{1}_{A}(Y\circ \theta^{k})d\mathbb{P}=\int_{\Omega}\mathbb{1}_{A}Yd\theta^{k}_{*}\mathbb{P}$$ why do we need to care aboout $\mathbb{1}_{A}\circ\theta^{k}$?

Comment: or the change of variable formula should be written as $$\int_{A}Y\circ\theta^{k}d\mathbb{P}=\int_{\theta^{-k}A}Yd\theta_{*}^{k}\mathbb{P}?$$ but why??

Comment: The second comment contains a formulation of the change of variables result as I use it (see e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) for the result as I had in mind when writing the answer). I'm unsure how you would get the result in the first comment since the integrand isn't written in the form $f \circ \theta^k$ for some $f$.

Comment: Yes. I also used the formula from wiki. However, I do not understand why $Y\circ\theta^{k}$ is over $A$ but $Y$ is over $\theta^{-k}A$, shouldn't $\int Yd\theta^{k}_{*}\mathbb{P}$ be over $\theta^{k}A$?

Comment: The source of confusion might be that I did skip a small step in what was my last line of equalities. I've now edited to add more details. Your second comment isn't quite right, I hadn't paid enough attention. It is true that
$$ \int_A Y \circ \theta^k dP = \int_{\theta^k(A)} Y d \theta_*^kP.$$
One way of viewing my answer is that I use the fact that $A = \theta^{-k}(A)$ to say that
$$\int_A Y \circ \theta^k dP = \int_{\theta^{-k}(A)} Y \circ \theta^k dP = \int_{\theta^k \theta^{-k}(A)} Y d\theta_*^k P = \int_{A \cap \text{Ran} \theta^k} Y d\theta_*^k P$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I just saw your updated comment. This makes great sense! Thank you for the clarification!